# While moving project from system to product partition how to resolve missing variant error?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-native-library

I am trying to move my APKs files and dependent libraries under product partition by setting `product_specific: true` in Android.bp files. My libraries depend on **libandroid_runtime** and **libnativehelper**. While I am building the project getting below errors for both libs -

```
Android.bp : dependency "libnativehelper" of "mylib" missing varient : 
missing variant:
  os:android, image:vendor.30, arch:arm_armv8-2a_cortex-a75, sdk:, link:shared, version:
available variants:
  os:android, image:, arch:arm64_armv8-a_kryo300, sdk:, link:shared, version:
  os:android, image:, arch:arm_armv8-2a_cortex-a75, sdk:, link:shared, version:
  os:linux_glibc, arch:x86, link:shared
  os:linux_glibc, arch:x86_64, link:shared
  os:windows, arch:x86, link:shared
  os:windows, arch:x86_64, link:shared
```

and `Android.bp : dependency "libandroid_runtime" of "mylib" missing varient :`

Answer (score 1):

libandroid_runtime and libnativehelper is only available for the product partitions .My Suggesstion is better replace these libraries with valid native libraries .

Comment: Yeah, I removed both libs but facing an issue with JavaVM and JavaEnv things in my code, if you have done it already please help me.

Comment: If your application still relies on android runtime . There is a way to bypass it and am not sure . whether it will work on product or not .https://blog.quarkslab.com/android-runtime-restrictions-bypass.html

Comment: Seems like this is for Android pie or lower, we are using Android 11- API level 30. If you got something please share, thanks.